# Java time between 0 and 24

Tags: java, time, formatting

I'm using a SimpleDateFormatter to parse a date/time. The problem is that if the time I insert is bigger than 24 it passes to the next day.

How can I do a date/time validation with strict time (between 0 and 24 -- I don't want a time of 25:00 to be interpreted as 1 day and 1 hour).

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
setLenient(false)
```

Should do what you want.

[`DateFormat.setLenient(boolean);`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 4):

This will throw an *`Unparseable date: "25:00"`* exception:

```
final DateFormat formatter = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
formatter.setLenient(false);
formatter.parse("25:00");
```

`lenient` by default is `true`.